# How do I receive a message after enabling loopback?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, multicast, loopback

I have my multicast (udp) sender/receiver program up and running. If I use setsockopt to enable loopback with the sender like so:

```
if(setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &loop, sizeof(loop)) < 0)
    error("loopback failed.");
```

and later on I send out the message to every subscriber, how does my sender get the message that's sent out? The sender doesn't store its own IP address and Port number and sent itself a message (basically subscribing to itself) does it?

So it should be something like:

receiver1 (subscription) -> sender

receiver2 (subscription) -> sender

when it's time to send:

sender (info) -> receiver1

sender (info) -> receiver2

sender (info) -> sender?  //how does this step work?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You still have to connect a socket before you transfer information. Unless you're using UDP.

Comment: I'm using UDP. Everything is working except for the sender getting it's own message.

Comment: Ahhh, well that makes more sense =) I had assumed you were using TCP, my bad. Don't have experience in that department, only the latter =/

Comment: I'm no expert on multicast, but, I'm confused by the fact that you list multiple sending steps for each receiver. Shouldn't there only be a single transmission that gets routed to all the receivers?

Comment: That's what my understanding was at first, but after looking at several examples, that wasn't the case. Maybe I wasn't looking at good examples?

Comment: @andy You were right! That makes this project so much easier. I'm still a bit confused about the loopback step. (Do I just subscribe to the multicast group?) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to subscribe to the multicast group, and then you should receive a copy of the outgoing data.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `loop` must be of type `u_char`, not `int`.  Of course, this will also change the final `setsockopt()` parameter to have the value 1.  I have no personal experience of this, but W. Richard Stevens says so in UNIX Network Programming (3rd edition), Vol. 1, Section 21.6, so it must be so.

He also says that using type `int` here is a common programming error.

Comment: It is of the type u_char. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it a common programming error? I think W. Richard Stevens is full of it; the size of these values seems to be implementation-dependant. If I do a `getsockopt()` on `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP`, it tells me it is 4 bytes long (whereas `sizeof(u_char)` is 1).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling loopback (which actually may be enabled by default, according to http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.1), you also need to subscribe to the multicast group.

It isn't necessary to send a separate copy of the packet to each receiver. If the multicast subscriptions are correct and you're on a network that supports multicast, then a single transmission is sufficient.

Comment: I ended up starting a new program from scratch. It took me less than 6 hours to throw it together(I have never made a program that fast with so much new material..holy cow). I had a bit of spaghetti code, but it worked! Thank you so much for your help.


You are correct about it being enabled by default, my professor wanted to make sure we knew how to enable it though. Again, thank you